# Android to MS SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server, json

I am developing an online android application in which I need to transfer 4 fields into MS SQL Server and insert it as a row. I am sure I would need need a web-service for data transfer mechanism. Now, Can some one please suggest where does this RestfulAPI code go in the andorid app or on my laptop. Can I manage just by installing MS SQL Server on a laptop and try to push data from Android app to DB via webservice or do I need anything more to be installed on the laptop.

Comment: you can use web api in visual studio mvc. try to install it first and create sample api.

Answer (score 1):

1-You must install Visual Studio and SQL Server. 
2-Create simple API. 
3-Upload your API to free hosting to test it. like "somee.com" 
4-Call the API from your app using volley or HTTP client.

A good tutorial I used before and it was helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pcM6teVdKk&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API approach for this. Using WCF REST Service you can access the data from SQL Server to Android.
Or you can connect your server without the REST APIs but this is not a good way,(I think)

```
public void ConnectToDatabase(){
try {

     // SET CONNECTIONSTRING
     Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     String username = "XXXXXXXXX";
        String password = "XXXXXX";
     Connection DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.188.4.83:1433/DATABASE;user=" + username + ";password=" + password);

     Log.w("Connection","open");
    Statement stmt = DbConn.createStatement();
    ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery(" select * from users ");


     EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.displaymessage);
    num.setText(reset.getString(1));

    DbConn.close();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

[HERE](http://www.tutecentral.com/restful-api-for-android-part-1/) is nice tutorials.

Comment: Thanks @DevendraSingh. I have developed a php page. In order to reach this php page from Android activity, I believe i should host it online. If so, can you help me know how to achieve this

Comment: no you can access locally if you are connected in same network

Comment: I want this php (connected to MySQL) to be online so that I can use the ip address in the MainActivity to connect. Using localhost, I can just keep it as a standalone page. By going online, the data from app can be stored on online DB server.

Comment: I solved my problem and got the answer. Thanks once again @DevendraSingh